# check php form verifications in when submit form by jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have created form with basic verification in html like this.

```
<form class="" action="submit/save" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="submit_form">
  <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required>
</form>

<a onclick="submitProduct()">Submit</a>
```

```
function submitProduct() {
$('#choice_form').submit();
}
```

then after click the `<a>` tag i have submit form as the
`$('#submit_form').submit();`
but `required` validations not sporting when submitting

Comment: I think you have answered your own question

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, ```$('#submit_form').submit();``` not working for me

Comment: No it obviously does not preform the validation unless you are moving the cursor out of the field. You will have to code the validation in js before you do the submit. And of course code it again in the PHP on the server

Comment: What `<a>` tag? Show that to us please, and how it links to your jQuery code. Why don't you just have a simple submit button in your form instead? As far as I know, running .submit() should trigger any HTML5 validation. So I suspect maybe something else is at the root of your issue

Comment: thanks @RiggsFolly . i have thanked about it. but i have tried to do some simple way from the others ideas. if its only option i will do it.

Comment: @ADyson its onclick funtion

Comment: Show it, please. The devil is in the detail. And show the JS function in full. And again, why don't you just have a simple, standard submit button instead?

Comment: This is the wrong code - `id="submit_form"` isn't the same as `#choice_form`. So that code won't submit your form at all.

Comment: preventDefault() ?

Comment: @flakerimi ??? There's nothing to prevent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [preventDefault without removing html5 validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161302/preventdefault-without-removing-html5-validation)

Comment: $('#choice_form') should be  submit_form, right?

Comment: @flakerimi that dupe candidate is about using AJAX, which isn't what's going on here. It's not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't submit anything at all, because it's using the wrong ID to identify the form. But assuming that was just a typo then...

Instead of using an anchor tag, just use a regular submit button, then you won't need any script:

```html
<form class="" action="submit/save" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="submit_form">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required>
</form>

<input type="submit" form="submit_form">Submit</input>
```

Answer (score -1):

i have entered this jQuery code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#submit_form').submit(function(e){
                if($(this).closest('form')[0].checkValidity()){
                    if(submitProduct() == 1 ){
                        return true;
                    }else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

`submitProduct()` is a my another custom function if that function done i have submitted form, if not done then form submission action killed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ });
```

it's helped me to use form validations also like 'required'

Comment: None of this code is necessary - see my answer